# Fetch the contacts When View Opened using cordova and ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, contacts, ngcordova

I am using [ngcordova contacts Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/contacts/) for accessing the phone contacts.I have the view template and controller. when contacts view will open show the list of contacts from device.
I using below code for accessing contacts

**contacts.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Contacts">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="padding">
      <div class="list">
        <div class="card" ng-repeat="contact in phoneContacts">
          <div class="item item-divider">
            {{ contact.name.formatted }}
          </div>
          <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <p><strong>Phone(s)</strong></p>
            <div ng-repeat="number in contact.phoneNumbers">
              <p>{{ number.value }}</p>
            </div>
            <p><strong>Email(s)</strong></p>
            <div ng-repeat="email in contact.emails">
              <p>{{ email.value }}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('ContactsCtrl', function($scope, ContactsService,$ionicPopup){ 
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {

     ContactsService.getAllContacts().then(function (contacts) {
        $scope.phoneContacts = contacts;

       });       
    })
   })
```

**services.js**

```
.factory('ContactsService',function($q,$cordovaContacts){


return {
    getAllContacts:function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var options = {};   
        options.multiple = true;
        $cordovaContacts.find(options).then(function(allContacts) { 
            deferred.resolve(allContacts);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

})

this method work fine on button click action.not working on view when open.how to resolve this

Comment: have you tried with ng-init()?and any errors with current approch?

Comment: @SaEChowdary Yeah I Tried not working...but in my another page have cordova camera plugin used.That page when i click the take picture button. again come with my contacts page the contact lists are loaded

Comment: i'm little confused now,can you be specific what is the actual requiremnt

Comment: @SaEChowdary when i open the contacts page fetch the contacts into ionic list

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122741/contacts